# How can I change the locale for my app programmatically via Swift?

Tags: swift, nslocale

I have a language selection control in my application, and I want to be able to set the locale accordingly during runtime. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(["fr"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

**Swift 3:**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["fr"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: can you specify where did you put this?

Comment: @daaniaal . Please could u help me how can i change the language without restarting the app

Comment: It seems to work only after you restart the app (iOS 11)

Comment: It doesn't work before restart in ios 11

Comment: This is beyond a wrong answer... I hope no one actually copied this...